# Write parquet files to S3 Sink Using Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

Conditions :

1. Code should read the messages from kafka topics and write it as **parquet file** in S3

Here I am using Pyspark sql to write Kafka and i am able write successfully as **JSON** file to s3 sink .

*Working code : *

Spark -2.4.4
package - org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4

```
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder \
        .appName("Python-EMR-KAFKA") \
        .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer") \
        .config("spark.shuffle.compress", "true") \
        .config("spark.io.compression.codec", "snappy") \
        .config("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR") \
        .config("spark.speculation", "false") \
        .getOrCreate()

final_df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("s3://sample-bucket/prod/cleansed/s4/")

    final_df.selectExpr("to_json(struct(*)) AS value") \
        .write \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "abc-qa.129.abc.com:9500") \
        .option("topic", "v1-pdr-auw2-ems-c5aecf6e-ndf") \
        .option("kafka.linger.ms", 10) \
        .option("kafka.retries", 3) \
        .save()
    spark.stop()
```

Now i want to store it as a parquet file in **s3** instead of json . I found the below solution from internet but my data is in TB and it take lot of time for conversion to avro .

```
 df = spark.read.json("src/main/resources/zipcodes.json")
 
  //convert to avro
  df.write.format("avro").save("/tmp/avro/zipcodes.avro")
```

Comment: Avro or parquet?

Comment: it has to be in parquet format at s3 sink .

Comment: But i see avro.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert from/to Avro. Spark's dataframe writer defaults to parquet, so remove any other `.format` function and just `write` to get Parquet files

However, it appears `final_df` is already read as a Parquet file in S3 and you're never modifying it, so there should be no need to duplicate it...

> read the messages from kafka topics

You're currently reading from S3, not Kafka. I'm not sure I see the need for Kafka here when your data is already in S3

Comment: 1) without  **.format** we cannot write to kafka topic . 2)  S3 is my source where i am reading it  - Other cross account is my s3 sink ..

Comment: You said you wanted to write as parquet to S3. I wasn't talking about the Kafka writer, only the S3 one. If S3 is both the source and destination, then Kafka isn't necessary. Also, Parquet can technically be written to Kafka, it just doesn't make sense to do so as it'd be individual records, not large files

Comment: Forgot about S3 .. Assume that consumer needs to write the data / store the message in parquet format . how can we achieve this

Comment: As answered (twice), you just write any existing dataframe to an output path. It'll default into parquet format. The Kafka writer, however, must have a schema of string or bytes under a value column, as is documented

Answer (score 0):

Spark doesn’t need any additional packages or libraries to use Parquet as it comes with Spark by default

```
//read json file into data frame
val df = spark.read.json("src/main/resources/file.json")

df.write.parquet("://S3_Path/file.parquet")
```

Comment: to publish message to kafka topic - the message has to be converted to key  value pair . here i am doing it as json .. but you cannot send it as parquet to kafka .. it should register the schema , for that we need to use avro